# Tomcat two-way SSL fails

Tags: tomcat, ssl, openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I am trying to setup two-way ssl for tomcat. I created a root CA and an intermediate CA. Then I created a certificate for tomcat server and a certificate for my client. Both certificates are signed by the intermediate CA. I then created a pkcs12 keystore for tomcat and imported server cert + intermediate CA cert + root CA cert into the keystore.

In the tomcat server.xml file, I configured the ssl connector with clientAuth="true", and keystoreType="PKCS12". I also set the values of keystoreFile, keystorePass, truststoreFile, and truststorePass.

In my client machine, I also created a pkcs12 keystore and imported client cert + + intermediate CA cert + root CA cert into the keystore. I imported the keystore into the browser.

When I restart the tomcat and try to access the tomcat server from my client browser, I get this: ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT. I used openssl s_client command to debug the connection. I get some errors:

SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert certificate unknown:s3_pkt.c: SSL alert number 46
SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:184

The retrieved certificate returned by openssl seem correct. Only the "Acceptable client certificate CA names" is strange. I guess it should list the valid CAs who could sign the client certificate. But what I see returned by openssl is basically the server DN, and not the CAs( intermediate or root).

I am wondering if anyone can help.

Thanks

Comment: More detail is required as to exactly which keystores you imported the various certs and how you configured the connector attributes.